# Request the branch.io API with python

Tags: python, branch.io

I need to request the branch io API, but the documentation lost me a little bit...

I need to get a deep link for each user, depending on their userid (that's the only criteria).
How should I do it?

Thanks a lot !

Actual code, which gives me a link which is always the same, when I change the userid:

```
import requests
import csv
import sys
import urllib
import json

#Constants
getrequest = "https://api2.branch.io/v1/url"
dic_test = {
        "branch_key": 'my_key_test',
        "user": {
            "userid": 40
        }
    }
test = requests.post(getrequest, data = dic_test)

# Always the same link
print(json.loads(test.text))
```

Comment: To be clear are you asking for the link only (https://docs.branch.io/apps/deep-linking-api/) or to create an API request to retrieve data using python.

Comment: Im asking for the link of each user, with python, depending on user user_ids

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far!

Comment: Done. Now, I have a link but always the same, with different ids

Comment: Does nothing happen when you change 40 to 41?

Comment: no. That's why Im blocked right now

Comment: Branch is not supported for Python.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to fetch new link for different user ids is:

```
getrequest = "https://api2.branch.io/v1/url"
dict_test = json.dumps({
    "branch_key": '<branch_key>',
    "data": {
        "$deeplink_path": "/<path_to_open_link>/", "user_id": "<user_id>"
    }
})
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
test = requests.post(getrequest, headers=headers, data=dict_test)
```

Data key can have varied parameters as per your requirement. Json.dumps(dict_test) and headers are mandatory

Answer (score 0):

It's my code exaple

```html
@receiver(pre_save, sender=Story, dispatch_uid="get_deep_link")
def get_deep_link(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    branchendpoint = "https://api2.branch.io/v1/url"
    headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
    test_data = {
        "branch_key": BRANCH_KEY,
        "data":{
            "type": "story_item_page",
            "entity_id": instance.id, 
            "page_id": 2228 
        }
    }
    post_request = requests.post(branchendpoint, headers=headers, json=test_data)
    jsonData = json.loads(post_request.text)
    instance.deep_link = f"<a href='{jsonData['url']}'>{instance.title}</a>"
```